# Devexpress How to update a bunch of Rows whitin Column FiedName = x while Column fieldname = y cell value ="00002"

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am very new to Devexpress and C#, need support from devexpress.
Does Devexpress have such command or method to update a specified bunch of row cell value.

1. Once i check my checkbox, the process will calculate what is my actual quantity available.
2. After the above process done, i able setcellvalue to my focusedrow cell for quantity available.
3. I looking for a method or procedure when the above process done, I want to update all my quantity available cell value when the item code are equal to my focusedrow.

if the above method available Devexpress, then will skip the time and prevent long loop script to check each GridView data row.

Thank You,
Brian

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no command that will update the entire grid at once--you will instead need to iterate through your data source (see: [Identifying Rows and Cards](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument642))

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyGridView.DataRowCount; i++)
{
    MyGridView.SetRowCellValue("FieldName", i, 131);
}
```

Comment: Ok, Then no choice, still need go back to For loop process script.
Anyway, thanks for the advice.

Comment: You could try to change the values at the data source level if you're that concerned about performance, but I doubt it would make much of a difference.

Comment: Hi Brendon, Issue solved using for loop statement. Thank you.